# Add 1 item from xml to tableview per day

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to take an already built xml, parse it, and add only the oldest item in the xml at first, and add 1 more each day.  The code used to parse is:

```
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"guid"];            
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubdate"];        
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            NSString *articleImage = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

            RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle
                                                      articleTitle:articleTitle
                                                        articleUrl:articleUrl
                                                       articleDate:articleDate
                                                      articleImage:articleImage
                                                              date:thedate] autorelease];
            [entries addObject:entry];

        }      
    }

}
```

How can I change this so it will only add the oldest item on the first launch of app, and so forth?

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713471/add-one-row-to-tableview-each-day-app-used

Comment: @HotLicks I have tried in the numberofrowsinsection to limit to 1 and wrote some code to add 1 each day, but it crashes the app with index 0 beyond bounds of empty array messages.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're not adding to the array.  Forget about the tableview for awhile and just figure out how to add to an NSMutableArray for each day.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly, except most table view tutorials are pretty overly complex and make it difficult as each are written for specific situations.

Comment: So forget about the tableview.  Once you have the array of items you want to present, putting them into a tableview is straight-forward.  If you conflate the two you'll drive yourself crazy.

Comment: I just can't wrap my head around changing the code in the OP to sort by date, and use NSUserDefaults to only add the first number of items that matches the number of days the app has ran.

Comment: That's what I'm saying -- get your head around accessing that XML and extracting your data.  Break it into steps.  First you need to order the data chronologically, if it isn't already.  Then you need to keep track of either element # or (probably better) last date accessed, and keep accessing one date newer each time.  In this case you've apparently already parsed the XML -- the ugly part -- and are dealing mostly with NSArrays, so it's just a matter of walking through to find your data.  Maybe get an array of GDataXMLElement items and then ask how to sort them, based on date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I put in:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"]) {

        // if there is no value for the key, set it to 0
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"totalDays"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"]) {
        [defaults setObject:@"32 01" forKey:@"currentDate"];
        //this will ensure that no one's start date ever matches current value
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    // get the current date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    // format it
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM"];

    // convert it to a string
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    // free up memory
    [dateFormat release];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"]){
    NSString *checkdate = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentDate"];
    if (![dateString isEqualToString:checkdate]) {
       //now if your current date is different from the last date it will add 1 to the total days key
        NSInteger currentnumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"];
        NSLog(@"The current number is %i", currentnumber);

        [defaults setObject:dateString forKey:@"currentDate"];
        [defaults setInteger:currentnumber+1 forKey:@"totalDays"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"The new number is %i", [defaults integerForKey:@"totalDays"]);
    }
    }
```

Then in the area for the NSPredicate I added:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate dateFromRFC3339String:@"2013-01-01T00:00:00-06:00"];
            NSInteger difference = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"totalDays"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"articleDate < %@",  [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(86400*difference) sinceDate:start]];
            NSArray *filteredArray = [entries filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

This last bit of code hopefully will do what originally hoped for.